# Как настроить слайдер(карусель) в шаблоне django?

Tags: django

С помощью `boostrap 4` я создал слайдер (вселял из шаблонов).
С помощью `django-filer` я создал папку к модели и вывел все изображения 
Но сам  слайдер(карусель) не меняет(прокручивает) изображения и выводит 2 изображения по id всего их 4.
Вот код укажите пожалуйста на ошибки:

```
<div id="carouselExampleSlidesOnly" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    {% for id in plots.imgPlots.files %}

        <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="{{id}}"></li>
    {% endfor %}
    </ol>
        <div class="carousel-inner">
            {% for img in plots.imgPlots.files %}
                <div class="carousel-item active">
                    <img  class="d-block w-100" src ="{{ img.url }}" alt="Третий слайд">
                </div>
            {% endfor %}
        </div>
    <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="prev">
        <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
    </a>
      <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="next">
        <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
      </a>
</div>
```

[image: Вот сам слайдер]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<div id="carouselExampleSlidesOnly" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
    <div class="carousel-inner ">
      {% for img in plots.imgPlots.files %}
        <div class="carousel-item">
              <img src="{{ img.url }}" class="d-block w-100" alt="{{id}}">
        </div>
      {% endfor %}
      <div class="carousel-item active">
        <img src="{{ plots.imgPlot.url }}" class="d-block w-100" alt="{{id}}">
      </div>
      </div>
    <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleSlidesOnly" role="button" data-slide="prev">
        <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
    </a>
      <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleSlidesOnly" role="button" data-slide="next">
        <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
      </a>
</div>
```

Это решение. Как оказалось нельзя поставить папку с файлами в шабло вам нужно создать ещё доп 1 фото и сделать его главным(active)

Comment: Можно создать в модели поле для подключения класса CSS active. И включить его только у первого файла.